# Failed to create an IDataAdapter object

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-job, sql-agent, execute-sql-task

I have SSIS package which consist Execute SQL Task step. Where package variable contains SQL query that executes on predefined SQL Server. There is no parameter mapping nor any more complex config.
This package is configured in SQL job step to execute on every certain scheduled time.
[image: Execute sql task config]

The job keeps failing on Execute sql task randomly, since i have retry attempts configured so it works mostly on its next attempt. The error from the 'Integration service catalog' says - "Failed to create IDataAdapter object. This provider may not be fully supported with the Execute Sql Task. Error message 'Internal connection fatal error'" I need to make it work smoothly without such fatal errors.
[image: SISS DB catalog Execution error]

I have already verified the SQL server connection, with the server owner and confirm the server is being used by several other process and do not have any issue to access it. It is just my SQL jobs keeps failing with this error. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using ADO.Net connection manager to connect the source SQL server. The windows server have enough memory. But RAM consumption stay between 90% to 95% on this server. I have several package configured in the same job executes step by step using same Execute SQL task config. But each time random job step fail but with the same error. I have checked Event viewer it has failure logs, but not much details it contains.

Comment: Talk to me about `SCM_Source_ADO_Net` Is that a local server, a server in a cloud VM or a database platform as a service? Given your description of intermittent failure, it smells like a transient issue that'd be solved by setting the retry logic on the SQL Agent job step

Comment: hi @billinkc , it is virtual machine, where SQL server is installed. And yes the retry logic has to be set and by which the job does run. But this has to be fixed, as retry logic is taking a lot of time when 2 or more Sql Job steps caught by same issue. What could be the reason behind this ?